# web page got blank when something being prompted by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

As a newbie to web development I am facing a strange issue, I am following a tutorial and doing exactly the same as the instructor did, but he did not face any issue like what I am facing. The issue is that the web-page got blanked when javascript prompted for some input, after input is done the web-page appears again.

Screenshots attached!

```js
var todo = [];
var input = prompt("What you gonna do?");
while ( input !== "exit") { 
    if(input === "list") {
     console.log(todo);
    }
    else if (input === "new") {
     //ask for new todo
     var NewTodo = prompt("Enter the new todo");
     //Add new todo to array
     todo.push(NewTodo);
    }
    var input = prompt("What you gonna do?");
}
console.log("You are quitting");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO PRACTICE</title>
    <script src="TODO.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>"List"- list all todo</li>
        <li>"Add"-Add a new todo</li>
        <li>"Exit"-Exit the app</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: See Attached]
Thank you in advance for giving your attention to it.

Comment: I'd advice you to find a better tutorial, that's awful ...

Comment: Can't recreate your issue in my system.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because of loading javascript inside `head` tag. More specifically, problem is because of `prompt` dialog. `HTML` inside `body` tag won't be loaded until `prompt` dialog disappears.

**Solution**

Move the `script` tag from `head` to just before the ending `body` tag.

As a tip, always load javascript **after** your html has loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO PRACTICE</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>"List"- list all todo</li>
    <li>"Add"-Add a new todo</li>
    <li>"Exit"-Exit the app</li>
  </ul>
  <script src="TODO.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*Javascript should be loaded after your html has loaded.*" but there is no interaction between JS and HTML here. When it's loaded will have no bearing on the operation.

Comment: @vlaz in this case, html won't be loaded until `prompt` dialog disappears.

Comment: @vlaz Prompting in the loop during the head parsing will block the body to be parsed anyway.

Comment: That would be a useful thing to add to an answer instead of (more or less) "here is the fixed code".

Answer (score 0):

Use the async defer tag to delay loading your javascript script till after other resources have been loaded. 
Example

Comment: Thanks you all for giving your time to it, i tried all suggested solutions but nothing works.
-The thing is why exact code of instructor runs smoothly while mine create issue?

Hopefully i got the answer soon.
Thanks!

Comment: HI @Kaythinks Thank you for your time, but if i use "async" it blocks the basic operation of this code. It do not add TODO in array & Show array elements. It just perform exit command.

Comment: What the async tag does is it calls the script asynchronously thereby not affecting the execution of other resources. Check your codes properly, you must be missing something.